# Select an favorite item of select element using jquery by text

Tags: jquery, html-select

I want to select an item of a select element by its text not its value using jquery.

I found this code:

```
$("#myselect").val("Some oranges").attr("selected", "selected");
```

but i try it to use my select option text but it only work with option value.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$("#myselect option").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "Some oranges";
}).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WAsLu/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo selector to find the option that contains the text value

```
$("#myselect option:contains('Some oranges')").attr("selected" , "selected");
```

Also if you are using jQuery 1.6+ look into using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`

```
$("#myselect option:contains('Some oranges')").prop("selected", true);
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/bskxY/)**

Comment: Just in case I've added the case insensitive derivatives

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector is case-sensitive

```
$("#myselect option:contains(Some oranges)").attr("selected", "selected");
```

As per its comments, extending contains selector with econtains for case-insensitive exact matches or icontains for case-insensitive partial matches:

```
$.expr[":"].econtains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || $(obj).text() || "").toLowerCase() == meta[3].toLowerCase();
}
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(meta[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};
```